# Delay when adding JLayerPane to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I need to make a hangman game in Java using Swing. I made my hangman figures in photoshop and used the full image as the background layer and then placed the other components on top using JlayeredPane. However, there is always a slight delay when I add the JFrame and open the window. I tried to create a button to add and remove on JLayeredPane when clicked but this caused an even bigger delay. Any assistance will be very appreciated.

```
public class Game_Screen extends JLayeredPane {
    
    private JLabel hangman;
    
    public Game_Screen() {
        super();
        super.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
        
        hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Game_Screen.class.getResource("/images/hangman10.jpg")));
        hangman.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
        
        add(hangman, Integer.valueOf(0));
    }
}
```

An example of one of the Panes in the game

```
public class Home_Screen extends Game_Screen {
    
    private JLabel title;
    private JLabel score;
    private JButton start;
    
    public Home_Screen() {
        super();
        title = new JLabel("HANGMAN");
        title.setBounds(490, 170, 942, 217);
        title.setFont(new Font("Press Start", Font.PLAIN, 100));
        add(title, Integer.valueOf(1));
        
        score = new JLabel("High Score: 0");
        score.setBounds(635, 330, 470, 67);
        score.setFont(new Font("Press Start", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        add(score, Integer.valueOf(1));
        
        start = new JButton("START");
        start.setBounds(635,400,400,120);
        start.setBorderPainted(false);
        start.setFont(new Font("Press Start", Font.PLAIN, 60));
        add(start, Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
    
    public void addStartButtonListener(ActionListener a) {
        start.addActionListener(a);
    }
}
```

JFrame Class

```
public class HangmanGame extends JFrame {
    
    private Home_Screen home;
    private Level_Screen level;
    private Win_Screen win;
    private Lose_Screen lose;
    private Play_Screen play;
    
    public HangmanGame() {
        super("Hangman");
        
        home = new Home_Screen();
        level = new Level_Screen();
        win = new Win_Screen();
        lose = new Lose_Screen();
        play = new Play_Screen();
        add(home);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);


    }
    
    public Home_Screen getHomeScreen() {
        return home;
    }
    
    public Level_Screen getLevelScreen() {
        return level;
    }
    
    public Win_Screen getWinScreen() {
        return win;
    }
    
    public Lose_Screen getLoseScreen() {
        return lose;
    }
    
    public Play_Screen getPlayScreen() {
        return play;
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
public class Controller {
    
    private HangmanGame game;
    
    public Controller() {
        //game = g;
        game = new HangmanGame();
        game.getHomeScreen().addStartButtonListener(new startButtonListener());
    }
    
    class startButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            game.remove(game.getHomeScreen());
            game.add(game.getLevelScreen());
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd use a `CardLayout` to flip between the home/level screens

Comment: Would I add the layout to the JFrame? Also can I use the layout with the LayeredPane as components?

Comment: The `CardLayout` would be added to the main component and yes, a `JLayeredPane` can be used within a layout manager.  My personal approach would be to make a series of images of the hangman and simple change the `icon` of the `JLabel`, it'd probably be easier and simpler

Comment: I will try that then, thank you. I do have a series of hangman images I just have not added them yet, I was using only one image to test. Would using CardLayout also help with the delay that I am experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to mess with you a little here, hang tight, I'm sure you'll appreciate it.

First, Swing is lazy.  When ever you make a change to a component or a layout, you need to tell Swing that you'd like things to be updated.

This means, when you add or remove a component you'd, typically, call `revalidate` and `repaint`.  Since you're not making a lot of use of layout manager, you could leave `revalidate`.

However.  A simpler solution here would be to make use of a `CardLayout`.  This allows to you to "flip" between views as needed.

One, glaring, issue I have with your approach, is the concept of responsibility.  Who is actually responsible for what.  You `Controller` is making a lot of decisions about what should happen, which, if you were using a controller properly might not be a bad idea, but, another idea might be to make each view some what independent and make use of an observer/delegate pattern instead.

For example, you don't really care "how" the `Home_Screen` starts, only that it can.  An observer would be interested in knowing when "start" occurs and take appropriate action.

You've kind of done this with the `Controller`, but I cringe at the notion that the `Controller` has a deep understanding of the components, this is just me ;).

Instead, I want things to be as dumb as I can make them, so if I need to change things, it's not a complete re-write each time.

Instead, in the following example, I've made use of a `CardLayout` on the `HangmanGame` and supplied a "delegate" to the `Home_Screen` which tells when "start" occurs (I don't care how, just that it does) and then allowed the `HangmanGame` to control the navigation.

This is generally a minor thing and you could argue that could use some kind of "navigation controller", but you'd need to do so in away which did expose the implementation details and ... it's a mess ... :P

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Controller {

    private HangmanGame game;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Controller();
            }
        });
    }

    public Controller() {
        //game = g;
        game = new HangmanGame();
    }

    public class HangmanGame extends JFrame {

        private Home_Screen home;
        private JPanel level;

        public HangmanGame() {
            super("Hangman");

            CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

            home = new Home_Screen(new HomeDelegate() {
                @Override
                public void startGame() {
                    cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "level");
                }
            });
            level = new JPanel();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
            setLayout(cardLayout);
            add(home, "home");
            add(level, "level");
            setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    public interface HomeDelegate {

        public void startGame();
    }

    public class Home_Screen extends Game_Screen {

        private JLabel title;
        private JLabel score;
        private JButton start;

        public Home_Screen(HomeDelegate delegate) {
            super();
            title = new JLabel("HANGMAN");
            title.setBounds(490, 170, 942, 217);
            title.setFont(new Font("Press Start", Font.PLAIN, 100));
            add(title, Integer.valueOf(1));

            score = new JLabel("High Score: 0");
            score.setBounds(635, 330, 470, 67);
            score.setFont(new Font("Press Start", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            add(score, Integer.valueOf(1));

            start = new JButton("START");
            start.setBounds(635, 400, 400, 120);
            start.setBorderPainted(false);
            start.setFont(new Font("Press Start", Font.PLAIN, 60));
            add(start, Integer.valueOf(1));

            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    delegate.startGame();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class Game_Screen extends JLayeredPane {

        private JLabel hangman;

        public Game_Screen() {
            super();

            hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/hangman10.png")));
            hangman.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

            add(hangman, Integer.valueOf(0));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(1920, 1080);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the initial load delay is expected of Swing, as it can take a few seconds for the Event Dispatching Thread to spin up and all the required initialisation to complete, but one part "might" be the loading of the image, although, before I started spending a lot of time worrying about, I'd focus on just making your game work

Comment: `[HangmanGame.]setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));` TL:DR; the frame is too small. -- Since many of the internal elements of the game (including images) are supposed to be that exact size, just pointing out that the frame (`HangmanGame`) needs to be larger to account for the window decorations.  Having said that, I note you stuck to using the OP's layout (cough) logic, so perhaps it's a minor point compared to that. ;)

Comment: It worked. The CardLayout was very useful and overall your implementation made a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, it's little bit of rushed shambles.  I did update `Game_Screen` to override `getPreferredSize`, but I otherwise agree